# How to return the unique elements of large data structures in go?

Tags: go

I am new to Go language and troubling in the code to find the unique elements in the go.

```
   var arr [10]string
      arr[0]="table"
      arr[1]="chair"
      arr[2]="table"
      arr[3]="table"
      arr[4]="chair"
      arr[5]="bench"
      arr[6]="table,chair"
      arr[7]="bench,chair"
      arr[8]="chair,table,bench"
      arr[9]="car"
```

The output should be like:

```
table 
chair
bench
car
```

I am really stuck on this. how to get the unique elements from the above array.
The array contains comma seperated values also but i need to print only the unique elements.

Pls someone help me on this.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea: use `map[string]bool` to collect unique elements, use `strings.Split` to split comma-separated list of words into strings.

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/sBopFGrzbX

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    arr := [...]string{
        "table",
        "chair",
        "table",
        "table",
        "chair",
        "bench",
        "table,chair",
        "bench,chair",
        "chair,table,bench",
        "car",
    }

    m := make(map[string]bool)
    for _, e := range arr {
        for _, w := range strings.Split(e, ",") {
            m[w] = true
        }
    }

    for k, _ := range m {
        fmt.Println(k)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include your code here in the answer too.

Comment: Hi Kostya, I have some doubt

Comment: @Michael, what this doubt is about? Can you explain?

Comment: i have some empty values in the array. how to skip the empty value                      farr := [...]string{
        "table",
        "chair",
        "table",
        "table",
        "chair",
        "bench",
        "table,chair",
        "bench,chair",
        "chair,table,bench",
        "",                                                                                                                                      
    }

Comment: I dont want to print the empty value in the list

Comment: @Michael, cant you simply just print/add to map `if w != ""`?